# mount.cifs error(2): No such file or directory when using a prefixpath

Tags: mount, cifs

I tried this command:

```
mount -t cifs //server/share/directory /mnt/directory -o credentials=/path/to/cifs.credentials --verbose
```

Response is:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=<IP of server>,unc=\\server \share,user=<username>,prefixpath=directory,pass=********
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

However, if I try the same command without the prefix path:

```
mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt/directory -o credentials=/path/to/cifs.credentials --verbose
```

It works, and I can access /mnt/directory/directory.

I get the same error if I specify the prefixpath explicitely in the options, i.e.:

```
mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt/directory -o credentials=/path/to/cifs.credentials,prefixpath=directory --verbose
```

Additional info:

- I am able to connect to the desired path using `smbclient //server/share -U username -W domain -D directory`
- mount.cifs version: 5.5
- Debian kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64
- I am able to connect on another machine using mount.cifs version 4.5 on Debian kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64

Any ideas why the prefixpath seems to cause a problem? This same path had been working recently; I suspect an update to a package on the Linux side or a Windows update is behind the new behavior.

Comment: Is this to a NAS? When you say you try "without the prefix path" the command looks the same. Is that a typo?

Comment: It's to a NetApp SAN. You're right, that was a typo--I've corrected it.

Comment: A NetApp support tech had be provide a packet trace, where they discovered that mount.cifs is sending //server/share//directory rather than //server/share/directory. This appears to be the cause of the problem (though not a solution).

Answer (score 8):

Finally found a workaround for this issue that works with our NetApp.  If you don't need DFS try mounting with the `nodfs` option.

```
mount -t cifs //server/share/directory /mnt/directory -ocredentials=/path/to/cifs.credentials,nodfs
```

Comment: We also use netapp. Thanks for this workaround, it saved my afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error `mount error(2): No such file or directory` while mounting (also a NetApp SAN).

Adding the `nodfs` mount option worked. However, I was missing the `keyutils` package. Once installed, mounting worked as expected without nodfs.

On Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt install keyutils
```