# cifs: Cannot cd into a directory

Tags: fedora, cd-command, cifs

For some reason I cannot cd into a particular remote directory for which I have access, it fails with:

```
$ cd Data\ Services/
-bash: cd: Data Services/: Invalid argument
```

This is how I mounted it:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //big.acme.corp/network/ ~/z -o username=myuser,domain=mydomain,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),vers=1.0
Password for myuser@//big.acme.corp/network/:  *********
```

I can access it just fine from my Windows 8 laptop (same username/password).

for reference:

```
$ ls -ald "Data Services"
drwx--x--x 2 myuser myuser 0 Dec 13 09:21 Data Services
```

---

At least on my side it seems this shortcut is seen as a directory:

```
$ find Data\ Services -type d
Data Services
find: ‘Data Services’: Invalid argument
```

As such I cannot do much with it:

```
$ cat Data\ Services
cat: Data Services: Invalid argument
```

or even

```
$ hexdump Data\ Services
hexdump: Data Services: Invalid argument
hexdump: all input file arguments failed
```

---

As suggested below, I tried again with the `noperm`:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //big.acme.corp/network/ ~/z -o username=myuser,domain=mydomain,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),noperm
```

Which gives me:

```
$ mount
...
//big.acme.corp/network/ on /home/myuser/z type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=big.acme.corp,domain=mydomain,uid=1002,forceuid,gid=1003,forcegid,addr=10.1.2.3,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,mapposix,noperm,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

That did not change anything:

```
$ strings Data\ Services
strings: Data Services: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Is the `Data Services` location a windows shortcut?

Comment: yes it is. Do I need something special on the unix side ?

Comment: Yes, unix/linux cannot follow windows shortcuts.  You should be able to open the `data services` file with vi/vim or your editor of choice and see the path to the actual directory.  Mount that path instead.

Comment: @Jesse_b `strings 'Data Services'` often quicker than `vi`/`vim`.

Comment: OK, so the shortcut is (usefully) being translated as a directory. Can you retry the mount, please, with the `noperm` option.

Comment: Very strange. I can't reproduce this at all with Windows 2012R2 as the server and Debian 9 (Stretch) on the client. A folder shortcut is seen as a file, not as a directory. 1. Is the File Server running Windows, or is it something specialist (maybe running a variant of SAMBA)? 2. From your Windows client, what does Data Services look like? (Folder? Shortcut? To something else on the same share?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual root issue was with the support of `DFS`. My version of CIFS was too old. Updating to a newer system did not solve all the issues, but I eventually stumble upon:

- https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_troubleshooting

Which gave me a more verbose error log I found out that:

```
[...]
[  687.037593] fs/cifs/dns_resolve.c: dns_resolve_server_name_to_ip: unable to resolve: MYSERV13
[  687.037606] fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: cifs_compose_mount_options: Failed to resolve server part of //MYSERV13/network to IP: -2
[...]
```

Updating my `resolve.conf` from:

```
search acme.corp
```

to:

```
search acme.corp mydoma01.acme.corp
```

I was finally able to call `mount -t cifs` without the `'nodfs'` option.
The symptoms are no longer an error and simply informative:

```
$ cd Data Services
CIFS VFS: BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\MYSERV13\network
[...]
```

I can finally access the content of `Data Services` without issue.

In conclusion:

1. One need some recent cifs-utils package,
2. Do not use `nodfs` option
3. Make sure your `resolv.conf` is correctly defined

Full thread at:

- https://lkml.kernel.org/linux-cifs/CA+7wUszkCoy_o2RJ76QESUH3S7NKG6RvFyVY+5sDcQA+dC6utw@mail.gmail.com/

nodfs reference:

- [mount.cifs error(2): No such file or directory when using a prefixpath](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164037/mount-cifs-error2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-using-a-prefixpath)

Answer (score -1):

Try options iocharset=utf8 and vers=1.0 when mounting the share:

```
mount -t cifs -o iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 //server/share /path/to/mount
```

That solved the issue for me.