# Object is remote in mounted CIFS on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cifs, shared-disk

I am struggling to mount a CIFS shared disk on Lubuntu 20.04. It can be accessed by `smb://myserver/files`. The command I am using for mounting is:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //myserver/files /mnt/remote_disk -o username=yyyy,domain=hhhh,password=xxxx,vers=1.0,nodfs -v
```

Up to here, everything OK. The disk is mounted.

But if I want to access the directory:`/mnt/remote_disk/parent1/parent2/son` It prompts:

```
bash: cd: /remote_disk/parent1/parent2/son: Object is remote
```

whereas if I step back one level:

```
/remote_disk/parent1/parent2
```

there is no problem.

I guess this is not a problem of permissions as I already checked that. In fact, if I configure Nautilus:

1. Open Nautilus.
2. From the File menu, select Connect to Server.
3. Input `smb://myserver/files`

I can access the files and folder within `parent1/parent2/son` directory, modify and read them. Do you guys have any clue of what I might be missing?

The dmesg outputs:

```
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -66
```

Comment: Maybe related? [Proper mounting Windows DFS Namespace in Linux / Object is remote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564881/proper-mounting-windows-dfs-namespace-in-linux-object-is-remote)

Comment: I saw that post but still no luck for me as I dont get the same error in dmesg. I'll update the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper mounting Windows DFS Namespace in Linux / Object is remote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564881/proper-mounting-windows-dfs-namespace-in-linux-object-is-remote)

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you found the answer yourself, please don't include that in the question, but rather post your own answer (which you may then accept after a defined minimum time). That way, the system knows this problem is "solved", so that users looking for a similar problem know where to look first ...

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by installing keyutils which was missing in my system and then I could execute the mount command without `nodfs`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keyutils
sudo mount -t cifs //myserver/files /mnt/remote_disk -o username=yyyy,domain=hhhh,password=xxxx,vers=1.0 -v
```